# Allow only "fit-in" modification with certain sizes for AWS Serverless Image Handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

We'd like to use AWS Serverless Image Handler only as a resize service for our website images stored in S3.

Since we don't need any other function, is there a way to allow only "fit-in" modification with certain predefined sizes to be accessible via frontend API?

E.g., we'd like to allow requests to
`https://<ApiEndpoint>/fit-in/<300x400>/<image.jpeg>`
with sizes 1500x750, 800x400, 300x150

and block any other modifications like "filters" or "crop" and any other sizes.

Could you please explain how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Serverless Image Handler is a [pre-packaged solution](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/serverless-image-handler/) that orchestrates the combination of API Gateway, Lambda, and Rekognition, along with some supporting services (CloudFront, Secrets Manager, S3).

You have two alternatives:

1. Reimplement the solution, configuring the API Gateway according to your needs and potentially excluding components that don't fit your use case (e.g., do you really need the global distribution provided by CloudFront?).
2. Fork and modify [the open-source solution](https://github.com/aws-solutions/serverless-image-handler/tree/main). This option is, in fact, quite similar to the first, with the primary distinction being that you won't start from scratch but will utilize the underlying technology of the existing project.